# Как разлогинить пользователя? в Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2

Я с помощю claims генерю jwt-токен для пользователя который правильно авторизовался, на калиенте каждый раз в header запросе передаю этот токен. В один момент администратор заблокировал этого пользователя за плохое поведения, как теперь разлогинить этого пользователя ?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749582/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, я решил что буду делать через SignalR